# Publish umbraco site on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, umbraco, urlrewriter.net

i'm stuck.
I upload my umbraco 7.1 site which i develop on visual studio 2012 thorough FTP to my server.
I created an Application Pool which work with .net framework 4.0.30319.

I start the site in the IIS and try to check it in the browser and i got this error:

> **Could not load file or assembly 'UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter' or one
>   of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified**.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load**
>   **file or assembly 'UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter' or one of its**
>   **dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter' could not be
>   loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Please help me to understand what should i do.
thanks,
Ido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your Visual studio has not uploaded all DLL's from the BIN directory.
I would try to check using a FTP client whether all DLL's (in the bin folder) are uploaded.

Comment: Thanks, i dreamed about it at the last night :) and when i got to the office i just include all the BIN folder and at the same time read your answer :))) it's a great mind !! thank you Boss !